# Trigger on Contact Record that updates related Account field based on specific criteria

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a custom CB field on the contact record called `connect_america_account__c`. When the value of this contact field is true, I would like the CB field value on the related account, also called (`connect_america_account__c`) to also be true. Here is the code I've constructed:

```
trigger ConnectA on Contact  (after insert,after update) {

    List<Id> AccID = New List<Id>();

    for(Contact con : Trigger.new){
        if(con.connect_America_Account__c = true && con.AccountId != null){
            AccID.add(con.AccountId);
        }
    }

    List<Account> accList = [SELECT Name, BillingStreet FROM Account WHERE id in :AccID];

    for(Integer i = 0; i < accList.size(); i++){
        accList[i].connect_America_Account__c = true;
    }

    update accList;
}
```

Here is the error message:

> Error:Apex trigger ConnectA caused an unexpected exception, contact
>   your administrator: ConnectA: execution of AfterUpdate caused by:
>   System.FinalException: Record is read-only: Trigger.ConnectA: line 9,
>   column 1

Comment: That error commonly happens when you try to update the data from e.g. Trigger.new. Line 9 in the code currently posted is not somewhere that an error could occur. Can you make sure you post exactly the code and error message that go together? Also con.connect_America_Account__c = True is always true; con.connect_America_Account__c == True is probably what you meant or better just con.connect_America_Account__c.

Comment: The error is what the end users sees.So I change the trigger to fire after insert, and the user is able to save the data, but the trigger is not executing properly.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you are not using Process Builder for this?  It would be a great use case for it.  Set the Process Builder to fire off when the Contact's "connect_america_account__c" = TRUE.  If TRUE, do a Record Update on the AccountId associated to the Contact.  Pretty simple problem that you have... so simple you dont need code!

Answer (score -1):

I know its too late. But hope it helps someone:

```
trigger ConnectA on contact(after insert, after update){
    list<contact> con = trigger.new;
    list<Id> accIdList = new list<id>();
    for(contact c: con){
        if(c.connect_America_Account__c == true && c.AccountId != null){
            accIdList.add(c.accountId);
        }
    }
    list<account> acc = [SELECT id, connect_America_Account__c from Account WHERE Id =: accIdList];
    for(Account a: acc){
        a.connect_America_Account__c = true;
    }
    update acc;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Read-only means that you can NOT change the value of the fields.  Records that fire an "After" trigger are read-only.  You need to change this to a "Before" trigger for it to work.  Something like this...

```
trigger ConnectA on Contact  (before insert,before update) {
     // loop through new contact values
     for(Contact con : Trigger.new){
           // get old contact value
          Contact contactOld = System.Trigger.oldMap.get(con.id);
          // check if field was changed from false to true
          if (contactOld.connect_America_Account__c==false){
              if (con.connect_America_Account__c==true){
                    // update other field to true
                    if (con.accountID!=null)
                           Account acct = [SELECT Name, BillingStreet FROM Account WHERE id=:con.accountId];
                    acct.connect_America_Account__c=true;
              }
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: this won't work -- Trigger.oldMap is not available in before insert context; you have select statements inside of for loops